# Why is this Autofac mock's lifetime disposed in a simple MSpec test?

Tags: autofac, mspec, automocking

I've got a base class I'm using with MSpec which provides convenience methods around AutoMock:

```
public abstract class SubjectBuilderContext
{
    static AutoMock _container;

    protected static ISubjectBuilderConfigurationContext<T> BuildSubject<T>()
    {
        _container = AutoMock.GetLoose();
        return new SubjectBuilderConfigurationContext<T>(_container);
    }

    protected static Mock<TDouble> GetMock<TDouble>() 
        where TDouble : class
    {
        return _container.Mock<TDouble>();
    }
}
```

Occasionally, I'm seeing an exception happen when attempting to retrieve a Mock like so:

```
It should_store_the_receipt = () => GetMock<IFileService>().Verify(f => f.SaveFileAsync(Moq.It.IsAny<byte[]>(), Moq.It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

Here's the exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedExceptionInstances cannot be resolved and nested
>   lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already
>   been disposed.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way MSpec runs the tests (via reflection) and that there's a period of time when nothing actively has references to any of the objects in the underlying lifetime scope being used by AutoMock which causes the lifetimescope to get disposed.  What's going on here, and is there some simple way for me to keep it from happening?

Comment: Sounds like e perfect fit for [MFakes](https://github.com/machine/Machine.Fakes) to me. It should abstract away the mocking frameworks and their intricacies. Is there a reason you are not using MFakes?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I may take a look at MFakes more closely, but I'd like to push through understanding what's going on with my usage of AutoMocks first in hopes of not making the same mistake in another context later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoMock` lifetime scope from `Autofac.Extras.Moq` is disposed when the mock itself is disposed. If you're getting this, it means the `AutoMock` instance has been disposed or has otherwise lost scope and the GC has cleaned it up.

Given that, there are a few possibilities.

The first possibility is that you've got some **potential threading challenges around async method calls**. Looking at the method that's being mocked, I see you're verifying the call to a `SaveFileAsync` method. However, I don't see any async related code in there, and I'm not entirely sure when/how the tests running are calling it given the currently posted code, but if there is a situation where an async call causes the test to run on one thread while the `AutoMock` loses scope or otherwise gets killed on the other thread, I could see this happening.

The second possibility is **the mix of static and instance items** in the context. You are storing the `AutoMock` as a static, but it appears the context class in which it resides is a base class that is intended to supply instance-related values. If two tests run in parallel, for example, the first test will set the `AutoMock` to what it thinks it needs, then the second test will overwrite the `AutoMock` and the first will go out of scope, disposing the scope.

The third possibility is **multiple calls to `BuildSubject<T>` in one test**. The call to `BuildSubject<T>` initializes the `AutoMock`. If you call that multiple times in one test, despite changing the `T` type, you'll be stomping the `AutoMock` each time and the associated lifetime scope will be disposed.

The fourth possibility is **a test ordering problem**. If you only see it sometimes but not other times, it could be that certain tests inadvertently assume that some setup, like the call to `BuildSubject<T>`, has already been done; while other tests may not make that assumption and will call `BuildSubject<T>` themselves. Depending on the order the tests run, you may sometimes get lucky and not see the exception, but other times you may run into the problem where `BuildSubject<T>` gets called at just the wrong time and causes you pain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Travis.  I believe I can now eliminate the first theory concerning the scenario having anything to do with async (at least as the sole cause), as I'm now seeing it with non-async methods as well.  I also think I can eliminate the second theory based on this answer from Alexander Groß which indicates that MSpec tests run serially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865859/how-is-static-object-state-shared-set-between-mspec-contexts.  I can confirm the third and forth theories aren't the case (multiple or missing calls to BuildSubject).

Comment: Well, somewhere along the line, the AutoMock is getting disposed. Without your actual tests and a repro, all I can do is guess at how.

Comment: I discovered that the container was being disposed :/